# clicking on approval form will have record data, if the record is existing in contact then it will update else insert

Tags: apex, community

```
List<Workflow_Instance__c>workfl= new List<Workflow_Instance__c>();
List<Container_Answer__c>container=new List<Container_Answer__c>();
List<Contact>con =new list<Contact>();

workfl=[select Id,Status__c from Workflow_Instance__c ];
container=[Select Id,Name,Supplied_Answer__c from Container_Answer__c];
if(workfl[0].Status__c=='Approved')
{
    if(con[0].FirstName==container[0].Supplied_Answer__c) 
    {
        //update contact
    }
    //else insert contact

}
```

Comment: Hi @Mishka, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: What are you trying to do?